# Генерация массива строк в С

Tags: c, массивы, строки, комбинаторика

Задача состоит в том, чтобы создать массив всевозможных строк типа "1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9", "12-3+4+567-89" и т.д., т.е. между цифрами может стоять плюс, минус либо вовсе ничего.

В соответствии с правилами задания вопросов в StackOverFlow, прилагаю свой ошибочный фрагмент кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char *arr[6561];
  char symbols[3] = {' ', '+', '-'};

  for(int i = 0; i < 6561; i++)
  {
    arr[i] = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 6561; i++)
  { 
    int index = 1;

    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
      strcpy(&arr[i][index], &symbols[i % 3]);
      i /= 3; index += 2;
    }
  }

  printf("%s", arr[4]);
}
```

При выполнении этой программы я получаю `segmentation fault`.

Comment: Заметим, что у вас весь массив `arr` указывает *на одну и ту же **константную** строку*...

Comment: @Harry Как это исправить?

Comment: Я написал свой ответ. Объявите массив строк (не указателей!) `char arr[6561][18]`, и копируйте в него создаваемые в моей программе строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементарно, Ватсон!

```
char arr[6561][18];

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char s[]   = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";
    char sig[] = " +-";
    for(int i = 0; i < 6561; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0, n = i; j < 8; ++j)
        {
            s[j*2+1] = sig[n%3];
            n/=3;
            printf("%s\n",s);
            strcpy(arr[i],s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Однако разве полученные строки сохраняются в памяти? Я не вижу здесь массива строк.

Comment: Тут печатается сразу. Можете в новый массив скопировать, но лучше сделать со строкой то что вы хотели сделать) и да, если вам значение вычислить, то я бы строку не использовал вообще.

Comment: @pavel Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы позже определить, можно ли некое число m представить в виде такой суммы. Так что мне необходимо сохранить строки и результаты вычислений в отдельные массивы.

Comment: А что, скопировать строку вы совсем-совсем не умеете?...

Comment: @Harry Я не особо владею функциями из `string.h`, и использование `strcpy` мне не совсем понятно.

Comment: Добавил в ответ копирование...

Comment: @Harry Благодарю за ответ. Всё вышло, как и ожидалось. К сожалению, отблагодарить могу только пометив ответ правильным и нажав стрелочку вверх.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте stl next_permutation для массива.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Example прилагается в статье.

Comment: И что вы хотите *переставлять*? :)

Comment: Очевидно, элементы массива symbols.

Comment: @Harry Однако нельзя менять порядок цифр, а из этого следует, что алгоритм всех перестановок не подходить под эту конкретную задачу.

Comment: Даже забавно :) Напишите, пожалуйста, код - хочется посмотреть, что получится...

Comment: @mydiamondsdancing в вопросе не сказано про "нельзя менять порядок цифр" - написано все возможные варианты. Вообще с перестановками тоже можно заморочить...